# Calculate the area of the tree

Tags: calculus, area, fractals

A DIN A4 sheet is divided into thirds. A rectangle is the root of the tree, the other two rectangles are each divided into thirds again. Two rectangles form the branches - one to the left, one to the right - the others are again divided into thirds and so on.

[image]

I want to calculate the area of that tree.

Do we have to write a formula using series or a recursive formula? But how exactly? Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Yes you need to evaluate the changing area of a step $n$ to the step $n+1$. Start by calculating it for $n=1,2\dots$

Comment: Is it not the area of the paper itself?

Comment: At the beginning we have the root which has area equal to 1/3 of the sheet. Then the two branches have are equal to (1/3)/3 = 1/9 of the sheet. Is this correct so far? @Atmos

Comment: Is this maybe something like $\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{3^i}$ ? @Atmos

Answer (score 4):

Each sheet gives origin to two other sheets according to

$$
S_n \to \frac{2}{3}S_n
$$

so the total area is given by

$$
S_0+\frac{2}{3}S_0+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2S_0 +\cdots = S_0\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k = 3S_0
$$

Comment: Could you explain to me further the map $S_n \to \frac{2}{3}S_n$ ?

Comment: At the step $n$ from a sheet with area $S_n$ we generate an additional area $\frac{2}{3}S_n$

Comment: Is this because if we consider a rectangle then the one part is taken for the tree and the other two again divided by three again? I am not really sure if I have understood that.

Comment: From a sheet with area $S_n$ we generate two additional sheets with $\frac{1}{3}S_n$ area each. Each leaf generates two other leaves.

Comment: Is $S_0$ the area of the DIN A4 sheet?

Comment: Yes. It is the DIN A4 area.

Comment: Why do we add at the area also $S_0$ ? At the tree haven't we at first a third of $S_0$, $\frac{S_0}{3}$ ?

Comment: The total sum sum is $S_0+\frac{2}{3}S_0+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2S_0 +\cdots $

Comment: But why isn't it (Say $R$ is the area of the root) $$R+\frac{2}{3}R+\left (\frac{2}{3}\right )^2R+\ldots$$ ? I don't understad why we calculate also the area of the DIN A4 sheet if the first part of the tree is the root which is $\frac{1}{3}$ of th sheet. Coudl you explain this further to me?

Comment: @MaryStar I took a sheet of old school graph paper and literally graphed the first three cases and then looked each time and the total area. I suggest you do the same. It will become incredibly clear!

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! :-)